# jdk1.8.0_25 no javac.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

I've seen other questions like this but not concerning JDK1.8.1_25. There is no java.exe fin in the bin file. In fact there isn't much in the bin file at all like there is in JDK1.7.0.71. So when I'm trying to execute java programs from the cmd line, nothing is happening. When I type javac -version there is nothing found. I'm trying to follow a Lynda tutorial but this isn't helping as it isn't doing the same as tutorial although tutorial is using an earlier version of JDK but really I would of thought the latest version should work.

My `%Path%` is:

> -C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin;

Wow didn't realise that was so long, that can't be right either can it !?!

Regards,

Caroline

Comment: If there is no java.exe or javac.exe file in bin folder of jdk1.8.0_25, probabaly your installation not perfect. Also in your path, you've configured the path to jdk1.7.0_71 instead of jdk1.8.0_25

Comment: Oh yes I see, I had changed that to jdk1.8.0_25 but changed it back again. No there is definitely no java.exe or javac.exe files anyway in the bin. I'll try re-installing I think - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long `%PATH%` is normal.

If your 1.8 JDK is incomplete (it can happen), revert your jdk in the `%PATH%` to previous version, and also `%JAVA_HOME%`.

Remember to close any console windows and restart any applications for it to take effect :)

To test:

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
java -version
```

Comment: Yes i think that's what i tried in %Path% - as you can see it's the previous version above.... I think I'll try re-installing jdk 8. Do I need to append the jdk8 file path to %Java_Home% too ? I'm just noticing I don't have that in my environment variables that %Java_Home% thing.

Comment: Reinstalling jdk8 should correctly set %JAVA_HOME%.  If not, then yes, you should google it to see exactly what the value should be, and set it yourself in Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings (System Properties) -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables -> User variables for Catess76 (or whatever your user name is.)

Comment: If your 1.8 JDK is corrupt, yes you should download it preferably from the official sun site and install again, and check afterwards that the `%PATH%` is correct. But if you revert to 1.7 then you just need to change the environment variables. Have a look again for `%JAVA_HOME%`, and note that it is in CAPS.

Comment: It's working now :-) although there is still no %JAVA_HOME%. path, it's working as i need it too - thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Your path should include (probably start with) the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.1_25\bin;
```

My `jdk1.8.0_05\bin` contains 53 files, 3,188,466 bytes, (including javac.exe,) and I doubt that they have drastically changed anything from 0_05 to 1_25, so if your `bin` does not contain anything like that, there must be something wrong with your installation. If so, then uninstall it and re-install it from scratch.

Also, if your path does really begin with a `-` character, or if it does really contain the string `QTSystem\C:\` instead of `QTSystem\;C:\` then you also have a corrupt path.  (Your java 7 should have never worked.)

Comment: Ok I think I'm going to try re-installing JDK 8 and see how that goes and change path to relevant version. Back soon. Thanks

Comment: Ok I've reinstalled and amended the QTSystem so it looks correct and not corrupt, and have added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin to the end. lets see if it works. But I still can't see a %JAVA_HOME% path as someone suggested it should have below.

Comment: it IS recognising javac.exe now in command line anyway - fabulous, thankyou

Comment: Be careful, the path is traversed sequentially, so if `jdk1.7.0_71\bin` is before `jdk1.8.1_25\bin` in your path, then the javac.exe selected will be the javac of jdk7.

Comment: It's working now :-) thanks to all you lovely wonderful clever people .. thankyou